# Including libraries to Android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to migrate an eclipse project to Android studio and i'm having issues due to libraries so i get this error

> Zipexception duplicate entry : duplicate entry: org/apache/http/annotation/GuardedBy.class

this is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.watchat"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

i've tried to use compile files('libs/Mylibraryname.jar') but i'm getting the same error
and this is my libs folder which contains all my libraries.

[libs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rejU.png)

Comment: some of your library are duplicate. It means library internally use same jar files. One way to check which one is duplicate is by adding them one by one. Moreover you should add libraries via gradle in android studio instead of adding jar files

Comment: search for libraries you have added . They also provide code for how you can add it via gradle. Most of them may provide, but if they not you have to add them as you have did them now

Comment: i've tried that and i'm getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that apache-commons-net and commons-net libraries are causing the duplication. Try removing one or the other and resync.

Comment: the problem is that my project uses them both (it means some classes need the apache-commons-net jar and others need commons-net), the two jars may have same classes that causing the error but they have also different classes which i'm using them both, so when i remove when of them i'm getting an import errors. How can i do ?

Comment: Try removing all three commons jars. Then add another 'compile' line like this: compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'

Comment: i"m getting an import error now : error: package org.apache.commons.net.ftp does not exist